# ¿Cómo manipular arreglos de estructuras?

Tags: c++

¿Alguien me podría explicar por qué no me deja ingresar información a un campo de una estructura? El programa se detiene cuando entra en el ciclo.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#define MAXCHAR 50;

struct Grupo{
    char clave_grupo[50];
};

struct Profesor{
    Grupo lista_grupos[8];
};

int main()
{
    Profesor profesores;

    int num_grup;
    cout << "\nNumero de grupos: ";
    cin >> num_grup;

    for (int i = 0; i < num_grup; i++)
    {
        cout << "Clave del grupo " << i+1 << ": ";
        cin.getline(profesores.lista_grupos[i].clave_grupo,MAXCHAR);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Si usas `std::cin::operator>>` deja el salto de linea en el stream, eso significa que cuando llegue al primer `getline` se lo va a saltar.  Probando el codigo es el unico problema que tuve, no se si a eso te refieres con: "*El programa se detiene cuando entra en el ciclo*"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema está en `cin.getline(profesores.lista_grupos[i].clave_grupo,MAXCHAR);`

Prueba usando `cin>>profesores.lista_grupos[i].clave_grupo;`

```
#include <iostream>
#define MAXCHAR 50;

using namespace std;

struct Grupo{
    char clave_grupo[50];
};

struct Profesor{
    Grupo lista_grupos[8];
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    Profesor profesores;
    int num_grup;
    cout<< "\nNumero de grupos: ";
    cin>>num_grup;

    for(int i = 0; i < num_grup; i++){
        cout << "Clave del grupo " << i+1 << ": ";
        cin>>profesores.lista_grupos[i].clave_grupo;
       
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Salida del programa:**

```
  Numero de grupos: 2
  Clave del grupo 1: 122
  Clave del grupo 2: 22
```

Espero que esto te pueda servir.